# How to combine scanner and multimap?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, multimap

I have two files and am trying to read each file line by line by using scanner. Also, I would like to combine these two file with the same Key(name) by using multimap in order to combine these two file into one. Here is the script I have so far. Can someone please give me the suggestion? Thank you.

**001.csv contains:**

```
David 188 Male doctor A  
Jacob 190 Male CEO    A+  
Sam   175 Male Engineer A-
```

**002.txt contains:**

```
David 80kg US3000  
Jacob 70kg US100000  
Sam   65kg US80000
```

Source code:

```
public class same_test{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        MultiMap multiMap = new MultiValueMap();
        Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner(new File("001.csv"));
        Scanner scanner2 = new Scanner(new File("002.txt"));
        while (scanner1.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scanner1.nextLine();
            String[] array = line.split("\t",2);
            String TheName = array[0];
            String score = array[1];
            multiMap.put(TheName,score);
        }
        while (scanner2.hasNextLine()) {
            String line2 = scanner2.nextLine();
            String[] array2 = line2.split("\t",2);
            String TheName2 = array2[0];
            String rs = array2[1];
            multiMap.put(TheName2,rs);
        }
        Set<String> keys = multiMap.keyset();
        for (String key : keys){
            System.out.println(key + "\t" + multiMap.get(key) );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use `Map<Integer,ArrayList<String>> instead`

Comment: @sankrish Thanks. However, my key is string (The Name). I didn't use arraylist at here.

Comment: Ok. Does your code prints the output you are expecting ?

Comment: Of course not. That is why i'm asking. I will definitely try your suggestion but that makes more complicated to me.

Comment: What's the output you see and what is expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plz share what problem you facing or output you getting.
I run you code, it works for me.
I used MultiHashMap.

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        MultiMap multiMap = new MultiHashMap();
        Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner(new File("/obp/f1.csv"));
        Scanner scanner2 = new Scanner(new File("/obp/f2.csv"));
        while (scanner1.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scanner1.nextLine();
            String[] array = line.split("\\s",2);
            String TheName = array[0];
            String score = array[1];
            multiMap.put(TheName,score);
        }
        while (scanner2.hasNextLine()) {
            String line2 = scanner2.nextLine();
            String[] array2 = line2.split("\\s",2);
            String TheName2 = array2[0];
            String rs = array2[1];
            multiMap.put(TheName2,rs);
        }
        Set<String> keys = multiMap.keySet();
        for (String key : keys){
            System.out.println(key + "\t" + multiMap.get(key) );
        }
    }
```

output

```
David   [188 Male doctor A  , 80kg US3000  ]
Jacob   [190 Male CEO    A+  , 70kg US100000  ]
Sam [  175 Male Engineer A-  ,   65kg US80000   ]
```

Comment: could you please share how did you import the class of multimap ?

Comment: import org.apache.commons.collections.MultiHashMap;
import org.apache.commons.collections.MultiMap;

Comment: I have tried but still failed. Here is my command :javac -sourcepath src/cc/openhome/Genic/MyjavaTest/ -classpath ./classes/commons-net-3.3/commons-net-3.3.jar -d classes src/cc/openhome/Genic/MyjavaTest/same_test.java                    Is there anything wrong ?

Comment: I seem you are  not able to compile your code. Could you share the error getting during compilation.

Comment: I figured it out. It's because I didn't include the correct library which is from org.apache.commons.collections Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is limited to the constraint that there is always a unique name like David. i.e. there will be only one David in the both the files.

Use

```
HashMap<String,Person> personMap = new HashMap<String,Person>();
```

Person Class will look like

```
class Person {    
String name;    
String sex;    
int height;    
int weight;    
}
```

Note : Mark fields as `private` along with `public` setters and getters

Where `Person` is your POJO class containing all the relevant fields for a person. You will create a new Java POJO instance for every name during the scan of the first file and put an entry of this object mapped with the name. then, in the second scanner loop, you can get the `Person` object out of the map with the name from the second file (which matches actually) and set the remaining fields in it. On completion of the method, you will get all the details in the form of `Person` instances mapped with their names

Comment: thanks, can I just combine this two map ? I know the multimap can match identical key for me but just not sure how to do that.

Comment: What's the output you see and what is expected?

Comment: MultiMap multiMap = new MultiValueMap();
    ^
    symbol:   class MultiMap
    location: class same_test

Comment: I expect to see "David 188 Male doctor A 80kg US3000"

Comment: I don't think you have a `\t` between each item in the file. Did you put the commons-collections jar in the classpath and import it properly?

Comment: Thanks your comments. I'm pretty sure about the files contain \t between each item. I have tried to import that but failed.

Comment: you're right. Maybe the problem is here, but I don't know to import. I have tried to add "org.apache.commons.collections.MultiMap;
org.apache.commons.collections.map.MultiValueMap;" but still failed.

Comment: Add this under your package name `import org.apache.commons.collections.map.MultiValueMap;`. Please add the jar file in classpath. [Link](http://mirror.cc.columbia.edu/pub/software/apache//commons/collections/binaries/commons-collections4-4.0-bin.zip) for Download the jar file

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out.